# S3 bucket showing different regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There seems to be different regions appearing across my AWS.

My S3 bucket says Ohio (us-east-2): [image]

however the URL of my bucket says us-east-1 (N.Virginia):

```
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/*****-bucket/?region=us-east-1&tab=overview
```

How do I find out what the actual region of my AWS is?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html

Comment: But I don't know what region my S3 is operating in

Comment: You can find it here: https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home

Comment: Thankyou that shows it.

Comment: great. Posted as naswer. Consider selecting as right answer.

Comment: The region in the S3 console URL refers only to the location of the console service endpoint that you are connected to.  For (presumably) faster responsiveness, the console is served out of a region that is (again, presumably) near your location.  It isn't clear why the console essentially provides this information to itself in the URL, but that's the only thing this value appears to represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose a proper region refer this official doc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html

To know which region your s3 bucket in, you can find it in amazon s3 console.
https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home